# javascript issue on reloading data from div element

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have something like

`<div id=X><textarea>DATA</textarea></div>`

DATA is populated via ajax request.
Now if I change text (by typing in textarea) and if i fire an event like on keypress/change then I get old DATA value (alert displays old data)...

```
    $(function(){
   $('#X').change(function(event){
     xx=$('#X').html();
     alert(xx);
  })
});
```

Comment: Tried `$('textarea').val()`?

Comment: somehow I still get same problem

Comment: According to JQuery API "The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to <input> elements, <textarea> boxes and <select> elements."

Answer (score 0):

`keydown` and `keypress` fire just before the input's value is updated. Try `keyup` instead. Also, the `change` event fires once the element loses focus, and as @jinggoy mentioned, should only be attached to inputs.

JSBin:
http://jsbin.com/vitomatocu/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Thanks for your input, even is getting fired but it shows old value which was populated via initial ajax request.. every time I press key alert gets triggered but I always see old value